# Remove shell folders from navigation pane in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, user-folders

Time ago I've used one of those strange tricks that let you customize Windows in some way, to remove the librearies and also the shell folders from the navigation pane (save/open file dialogs) in Windows 7, it worked fine but I don't remember where I've seen this trick and anyways I'm not using Windows 7 anymore.

How I can remove the shell folders from the navigation pane in Windows 8.1 x64?:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete everything from this folder:

> C:\Users\Username\Links

Otherwise, just right click each folder and select remove.

Comment: Those are my custom links, not the shell folders. I have some personal folders inside but any shell folder inside that directory (Downloads, Documents, Pictures, Videos, etc... any).

Comment: If you want to compltely remove the folders, I'm afraid they're required by Windows to load your profile properly when you logon. What you can do is change the location of these folders to your liking by right clicking each folder, going to properties and selecting a different location in Target field.

Comment: I only would like to remove/hide them from the save/open file dialogs. thanks